# VBA Programming with multiple conditions using ComboBoxes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am new to VBA programming and working through excel VBA programming by myself and have a question involving multiple ComboBoxes that are being used to determine the value of a single cell.

I have 2 ComboBoxes.

Right now I am using something close to this syntax

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "A" and Me.ComboBox2.Value = "2" Then 
Range("A2").Value = Range ("B6").Value
Else Range("A2").Value = Range("B7")
End If
```

The code is not working. I am not getting anything return in what would be A2.

I am assuming that the entries in the ComboBoxes are strings of any sort and are correctly put into the code.

Any more troubleshooting help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the combo boxes in a user form or on a worksheet?

Comment: The Combo Boxes are on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to capture the combobox2 value in a string variable

```
dim str_comboBox2 as string
str_comboBox2 = Me.ComboBox2.value

If Me.ComboBox1.value = "A" and str_comboBox2 ="2" then
```

As it might be interpreting your entry as a number thus not satisfying the IF statement.

Or change to:

```
If Me.ComboBox1.value = "A" and Me.ComboBox2.value = 2 then
```